# how to send email from hotmail and yahoo?

Tags: android

I am following answer no 8 from the following post:

[SMTP Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app)

it is working fine for the gmail. 
but not working for hotmail and yahoo.
i define following smtp server

```
SMTP Server for hotmail:
smtp.live.com

SMTP Server for yahoo:
plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com
```

how this code work for hotmail and yahoo?

Answer (score 4):

Read about :

- Yahoo [smtp](http://techblissonline.com/yahoo-pop3-and-smtp-settings/) settings and
- Hotmail [smtp](http://techblissonline.com/hotmail-pop3-and-smtp-settings/) settings

Note the port numbers and other details

for example, hotmail

```
private String mailhost = "smtp.live.com";
```

and

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");   
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");   // because of SSL
```

Comment: get the following error : javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.live.com, port: 587;

Comment: second error : com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html

Answer (score 0):

I am able to send mail using this code:
Make sure you perfectly checked your smtp port and smtp host.

```
enter code here



 private String mailhost = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";  

 // private String mailhost = "plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; 
    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
```

Comment: it works fine for me even for company domain like smtp.yourcompany.com

Comment: let me try, do u know which port and connection type  will be used for hotmail